# Connect to multiple namespaced movegroups from single C++ node

Tags: c++, moveit, ros-melodic, move-group-interface, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a two robot set up that uses SMACC state machines in C++, with MoveIt!. In order to control multiple robots from a state machine, I need to run the state machine in a node that is reachable by both robots, but to run multiple `move_groups` I need to run each robot in a separate namespace.

I am wondering if there is a way to connect to `MoveGroupInterface` from inside my C++ node, specifying, that the `move_group` node is located in a namespace, sort of as in the pictures below. Otherwise, if I would launch the `move_group` outside of the namespace, when launching the other robots `move_group`, it would kill the first one and so on.

[image: image description]

rqt_graph showing the node connected to `move_group` inside the namespace.

[image: image description]

rqt_graph showing the node outside of the namespace

Edit 1:

[move_group_interface.h](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h) seems to have a `struct Options` which takes a `ros::NodeHandle` parameter, but I am not entirely sure about the correct way how to pass the wanted  `NodeHandle{/namespace}` to it.

Edit 2: Disregard opinion in Edit 1!

Related links:

[Similar github issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2364)

[Similar ros answers problem](https://answers.ros.org/question/277802/ignore-namespace-when-creating-movegroupinterface/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393108/connect-to-multiple-namespaced-movegroups-from-single-c++-node/) by [sniegs](https://answers.ros.org/users/70243/sniegs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2021-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The trick seems to be that you open a NodeHandle with a namespace, then pass the NodeHandle object to the MoveGroupInterface constructor.

Please post a comment here if you get it working.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sniegs](https://answers.ros.org/users/70243/sniegs/) on 2022-01-05**:
Do you mean to create for example ros::NodeHandle nh{/ns}; and pass it to the MoveGroupInterface constructor? That seems as the correct way to go, as the MoveGroupInterface has the Options structure which also takes that as one of the variables, but I seem to be having problems with how to pass the NodeHandle object to the constructor, which might or might not be a problem of my C++ programming knowledge.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-01-05**:
Your nh syntax above is wrong for c++. You just create the `Options` object using 3 arguments:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh("ur5");
Options opt("arm_group", "robot_description", nh);
```

**Comment by [sniegs](https://answers.ros.org/users/70243/sniegs/) on 2022-01-06**:
Yes, thank you so much, I got it working! So the syntax would be

```
ros::NodeHandle nh("/ur5");
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Options options("arm_group", "robot_description", nh);
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group(options);
```

and now MoveGroupInterface is launched in the namespace set in nh!